# Having Issues with Python debugging in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am pretty new to all this so bare with me, I am confused on what is going on with my setup to debug my python code. I have the most current updates for vscode, and the latest python 3 (3.8.5 64-bit). However when I try to start a debug, I get an time out error along with "Command 'cmd' not found, but there are 16 similar ones." Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What does this mean: "but there are 16 similar ones."   You mean there are 16 cmd.exe files in your path or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your default terminal with the following steps:

1. press **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open a new terminal;
2. click the drop-down menu and choose **Select Default Shell**:
   [image]
3. select **Command Prompt**:
   [image]

Then reload window to make the setting work. You can try this to see if the problem goes away.